# Singly Linked List

Tags: c++, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I have a project from 
https://hotfile.com/dl/253309046/133284f/4_SinglyLinkedList.rar.html

The function `insertOrdered()` inserts scores in order.

My questions is: can this loop be rewritten without using a "previous" variable?

```
SinglyNode* current = head;
SinglyNode* previous= NULL;
while (current != NULL)
{
    if(newNode->score >= current->score)
        previous = current; 
    else
        break;
    current = current->next;
}

newNode->next   = previous->next;
previous->next  = newNode;
```

Comment: Why would you want that? It will just make the code unnecessarily complex. Oh and by the way, you need to check for `previous == NULL`, if you have to insert before the current head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
SinglyNode* current = head;
if(current == NULL) {
    head = newNode;
}
else if(newNode->score < current->score) {
    newNode->next  = current;
    head  = newNode;  
}
else {
    while (current->next != NULL)
    {
        if(newNode->score < current->next->score)
          break;
        current = current->next;
    }

    newNode->next  = current->next;
    current->next  = newNode;  
}
```

Comment: I don't agree with accepting this answer. If the `head` pointer is null, then `current` is null. And so `current->score` dereferences a null pointer: fail!   Please wait a few hours or days before accepting answers.

Comment: In the question was a part of working program. From which it was an obvious that head here can't be NULL.

Answer (score 0):

get the previous variable's(say p) value in another variable(say x) and use the x instead of p.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to first check if it should be inserted before the head. If not then use a loop similar to your but compare against `current->next` (if not `NULL`), then when the loop ends the new node should be inserted between `current` and `current->next`, i.e. `current` is used as `previous` in the code you have now. If `current->next` is `NULL` then insert at end.

Answer (score 0):

Not able to test this, but moving the new node setup code into the if block should allow you to remove the previous variable.

```
SinglyNode* current = head;
while (current != NULL)
{
    if(newNode->score >= current->score) {
        newNode->next  = current->next;
        current->next  = newNode; 
    }
    else break;
    current     = current->next;
}
if(current == NULL) { // got to end of list
    current->next  = newNode;
    newNode->next  = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot eliminate the "previous" variable, but you can disguise it; and furthermore, you can structure the loop so that it is the **only** iteration variable.

Of course to insert the new, you need to update the previous node to point to it.

You can do that from the current node by looking ahead in the list and handling various cases.

Another way is to keep a pointer to the pointer field in the previous node.

```
node **ppnode;

for (ppnode = &head;
     *ppnode != NULL && (*ppnode)->value >= newnode->value;
     ppnode = &(*ppnode)->next) 
   ; /* empty body */

newnode->next = (*ppnode) ? (*ppnode)->next : NULL;
*ppnode = newnode;
```

Here, instead of using a `current` pointer to point to the current, we use a `ppnode` pointer which points to the current node indirectly. Instead of pointing to that node, it points to the pointer which points to that node (and so it must be suitably typed: it is a pointer to pointer: double star).

The pointer to the first node is the list `head` variable, so `ppnode` points to that `head` variable initially. The pointer to every other node after that is the `next` field of the previous node: each one of these `next` fields is really like a `head` of the rest of the list.   So with this one `ppnode` variable, we keep track of the location within the previous node that must be updated, without keeping track of the previous node itself. And this lets us handle the front of list case where there is no previous node.

Let's trace through the case that `head` is null (the list is empty).

`ppnode` points to `head`. But `*ppnode` is null, and so the loop body never executes.

Since `ppnode` points to `head`, the lines:

```
newnode->next = (*ppnode) ? (*ppnode)->next : NULL;
*ppnode = newnode;
```

have the same meaning as:

```
newnode->next = head ? head->next : NULL;
head = newnode;
```

The conditional check in these lines handles the case when the new node is added to an empty list or to the tail of a nonempty list. If the list is empty or all the values in it are smaller than the new value, then the loop terminates with `ppnode` pointing at the list's null terminator, which is `head` if the list is empty, or else the `next` field of the tail node. Since `*ppnode` is null, we cannot deference `(*ppnode)->next`. There is no next; the new node is the last node and its `next` must be nulled.

Now let's look what happens in the case that there is a head node, and its value is greater so that the new node must be inserted at the front. In this case `ppnode` points to `head`, as before, and the `*ppnode != NULL` condition is true. However the `(*ppnode)->value >= newnode->value` condition fails and so the loop never executes.

Now, again, we are executing the equivalent of this code:

```
newnode->next = head ? head->next : NULL;
head = newnode;
```

But this time `head` is not null, and so `newnode->next = head->next`, and, as before, `newnode` becomes the new `head`.

All the other cases proceed from these two: except instead of `head`, the action plays out using the `next` pointer of the previous node, which is like the head of the rest of the list.